# Pandas DataFrames in Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have an excel file with several tabs, each reporting quarterly account values.
I want to create a dataframe to group_by accounts and report by Period.
I manage to generate a period_index and read the file with pd.ExcelFileParse (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) and get a dict with tab names as keyes and the period-data as dataframes. So far, good.

Now, when I loop through the dict to either append the different data frames or concatenate them, Pandas generates errors that only series and DataFrames can do that, not the dict object.

How can I generate one DF from the different dataframes  in the dict?

thanks in advance,
kind regards,

Marc

Comment: Are you able to get anywhere by doing this (where `d` is your dict)?: `df = pd.concat([v for v in d.values()])`

Comment: Yes, that works. thank you!